# windows live authentication in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, authentication, live

I need to get back an verification code and ultimately an access token for a given windows live ID so my app can access the Microsoft service.

I'm really out of my element on this one and any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure ... Can you check

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/LiveMeshMobile/thread/3ce66392-51e9-4717-b7cd-721e3674c6ef

https://www.mesh.com/Web/Developer.aspx